# To use variable out of its function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting JSON data with $.getJSON function in jQuery in real-time. I assigned this data to a variable in this function. But I can't use this variable out of this function.  I want to use this variable everywhere in jQuery codes. What can I do?

```
var anlikwar;
var anlikflood;
$.getJSON("ayarlar.asp",function(veri) {
$(".wfloodnum").html("Şu anki değer:" + veri.floodwarno);
});
var yenile = setInterval(function() {
$.getJSON("ayarlar.asp",function(veri) {
$(".wfloodnum").html("Şu anki değer:" + floodwarno);
anlikwar = veri.floodwarno;
});
},100);
$.getJSON("ayarlar.asp",function(veri) {
$(".nfloodnum").html("Şu anki değer:" + veri.floodnum);
});
var yenile = setInterval(function() {
$.getJSON("ayarlar.asp",function(veri) {
anlikflood = veri.floodnum
$(".nfloodnum").html("Şu anki değer:" + veri.floodnum);
});
},100);
```

Comment: Code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Add some code, this way you make downvoters trigger happy

Answer (score 1):

You could (as Kevin said define the variable externally) or you could define the function you want to perform on the variable and call it like this.

```
function doSomething(thedata)
{
    /// yay we have data
}


function getData() {
   $.getJSON()
     .done(function (r) {
        doSomething(data);
     });
}
```

This is generally considered better than having a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define your variable outside of the function.

```
var data;

function getData() {
    $.getJSON().done(function(result) { 
        data = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got a hunch the OP is trying to assign the response to a variable before it actually is returned from the server.

Comment: More than likely. I doubt we'll ever hear back from them either

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I can tell you are assigning the data to a variable before it is received.

AJAX is asynchronous, by definition - look up the acronym. You cannot assign the data you receive in the response until you actually receive it from the server. Use the callback function success (or done) to do what you want with the data.

```
$.getJSON({
    //..params
    //..params
    success: function(r,status,jqXHR) {
        //your data is in variable r
    }
}).done(function(r,status,jqXHR) {
    //your data is in variable r
})
```

All that being said, on stackoverflow if you have a question related to your code, you should really post it.